# OIDC on the backend, redirect from frontend

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, quarkus

I am implementing a small tool with integration with GitLab as Identity Provider.
React on the frontend, Quarkus on the backend.

I have configured my backend as `web_app` and this part is working. After entering `localhost:8080/auth` (backend) Quarkus redirects me to the GitLab, after login I am redirected back to the backend which returns `UserInfo` as JSON.

Now I want to add frontend part based on sessions (cookies). According to the [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-web-authentication#single-page-applications) I set `quarkus.oidc.authentication.java-script-auto-redirect=false` and my frontend receives 499 code and then using `window.location.assign` browser opens backend -> GitLab -> login -> `UserInfo` as JSON. And at the end, flow stops on the backend, and I am not able to get back to the frontend.

1. Is my flow correct? Is it even possible to achieve this (OIDC on the backend and session for frontend)?
2. How I can wrap `window.location.assign("http://localhost:8080/auth")` to hold frontend context (I need to use this, otherwise redirect to GitLab will fail with CORS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, tries and fails, implementation is ready.

Flow:

- frontend shows button to log in with GitLab
- button is a link to the backend with additional HTTP Header `'X-Requested-With': 'JavaScript'`
- if user is not authenticated, backend returns 499 code and frontend using `window.location.assign` redirects to the GitLab log-in page
- GitLab redirects to the backend (tokens are stored there)
- backend redirects to the frontend (at this point backend has user's tokens and frontend has cookie from backend for session)

Both - frontend and backend - are working on the same domain.

Implementation - https://gitlab.com/hakkie-it/time-tracker/time-tracker